# Wordpress plugin for managing/tracking mp3... say for a band site?

Tags: php, wordpress

Working on a blog for a friend of mine that wants an easy way to upload / manage and get stats on tracks being played.  (the last, the stats, being less important) just an easy way to upload tracks, maybe group them into a CD/Playlist.

Anything like this for WP, our should I build my own.

Comment: "tracks being played" -- where?

Comment: As far as the upload/manage functionality, what prevents you from using the built-in media manager?

Comment: Might wanna try the [Wordpress SE Site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you could just use the media manager if you want something more advance there are gobs of media manager players for WordPress. I did a quick search on http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=audio+player